# cPanel SSL installation

Tags: web-hosting, https, cpanel, security-certificate, vps

I've tried transferring SSL issued by GoDaddy to Linux based server. The website was originally hosted in Windows. After the installation is completed, I got a message like this in cPanel:

```
Certificate ID: ***********
Domains: xxxxsomethingxxxxx.com
Issuer: GoDaddy.com, Inc.
Key Size:   2,048 bits
Expiration: Feb 10, 2015 10:05:10 PM
```

Does that look fine? Does the `Issuer` still remain as GoDaddy? Now how do I test to see if this is in fact working?

After installing the SSL in the Linux server, do I now need to do something in GoDaddy or in the previous Windows server to indicate that the SSL has now been transferred to the new server?

Comment: You say transfer, did you re-issue a new csr and replace the certificate? If not then the public and private keys will be incorrect for the specific website. Also, don't forget to make sure openSSL has been patched against the heart bleed bug.

Comment: @LiamSorsby I did issue a csr and took from there. If the keys were incorrect, I wouldn't have received the "installation completed" message as above, right? However I did re-key the certificate in GoDaddy and now I am also getting `Error code: sec_error_revoked_certificate` in Firefox but in Chrome, everything looks alright. Any clue?

Comment: Basically everytime you install a ssl cert onto a server you should create a new csr and revoke the old certificate and give the new csr to generate a new certificate. More then likely the above error is being shown because the you have put the certificate onto the server of which the csr doesn't match (which is unlikely) or you have added the old certificate which you have revoked. Firefox may do additional checks on your ssl certificate

Comment: Ok. So in order to get rid of the error message, can I create a new CSR with a new private key and install the new certificate? Do I need to re-key the certificate again?

Comment: You will need to request a csr on the server you wish to install it on and then click on replace certificate add the new csr and then this should install fine on your server.

Answer (score 1):

SSL certificates do not need to be transfered in the same way that domain names do.   You can use the same certificate on multiple machines at the same time.

The only reason to remove the certificate from your old Windows server would be to prevent it from falling into the wrong hands.

You can test that your setup is working by visiting your site.   If your domain name hasn't been switched to point to your new host yet, you can check it beforehand by modifying your [local DNS hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29).

Answer (score 0):

How to test it? Just go to `https://yoursite.com/`, if it pulls up, it works!